# How can I zip multipule List in Scala?

Tags: scala

Let's take an example, I have a matrix: Array[Array[Int]], m * n, and I want to zip m Lists(rows).

Input m*n matrix:

```
val list = List( //m Lists
    List(1,2,3,...,n), //n Int in each List
    List(11,12,13,...,n),
    ...,
    ...,
    ...,
    List(91,92,93,...,n)
)
```

Output sould be:

```
List( // n Lists
    List(1,11,...,91), //m Int in each List
    List(2,12,...,92),
    List(3,13,...,93),
    ...,
    ...,
    ...,
    List(n,n,...,n)
)
```

In python, I could simply do

```
map(list, zip(*matrix))
```

I have already seen some solutions, however, they only fit for zipping lists of certain count. Is there a concise solution in Scala, like Python does?

Update: 
Thank to the answer, I figure out the keyword in Scala is **transpose**, please check the similar question: [How to perform transpose on List of Lists in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135811/how-to-perform-transpose-on-list-of-lists-in-scala)

Comment: So you essentially want to transpose the matrix? It's not exactly clear what you want the output of the operation to be. Perhaps an example input/output or an output type would help clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the sub arrays have the same number of elements, you can use `Array.transpose` method:

```
val arr = Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(4,5,6))
// arr: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6))

arr.transpose
// res8: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 4), Array(2, 5), Array(3, 6))
```

Comment: That is exactlly what I want to do, the keyword in scala is transpose. Thanks. In addition, if the sub arrays do not have same length, it will looks like: 
    val arr = Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(4,5))
    // arr: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5))

    arr.transpose
    // res8: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 4), Array(2, 5), Array(3))